# Saving styles for all layers using PyQGIS - SLD, QML, databases

Tags: pyqgis, style, spatial-database, sqlite, qgis-3

I wrote a script (for QGIS 3) that saves styles for all visible vector layers in QML and SLD files:

```
import processing
self=qgis.utils
layers = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()

for layer in layers:
    layerType = layer.type()
    if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        name = layer.name()
        pathqml = 'C:/Style/QML/'+str(name)+'.qml'  
        pathsld = 'C:/Style/SLD/'+str(name)+'.sld'  
        layer.saveNamedStyle(pathqml)
        layer.saveSldStyle(pathsld)
```

How can I do this for the layers from SQLite, PostgreSQL/PostGIS ?

Comment: Are the sqlite and postgis layers not loaded into your Q project?  Are you wanting to save those layer styles to a folder or to a database?

Answer (score 2):

This is what i do to write all styles to the Postgresql database, after setting up a project:

#### Writing all styles to the database

```py
mapGeometryType = {
    0: "Point",
    1: "Line",
    2: "Polygon",
    3: "UnknownGeometry",
    4: "NullGeometry",
}

layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()

for layer in layers.values():
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        if mapGeometryType[layer.geometryType()] != "NullGeometry":
            layer.saveStyleToDatabase(name=layer.name(),description="Default style for {}".format(layer.name()), useAsDefault=True, uiFileContent="")
```

The code has an additional condition based on `layer.geometryType()` to avoid writing styles for non geographic data (from tables used just for joins or relations).

Styles are written on `public.layer_styles` table on the database where the layer comes from.

Answer (score 1):

To save the style into a database use:

```
layer.saveStyleToDatabase("NameOfStyle","Description",True,"uiFileContent")
```

Comment: here database mean postgres , what if there are multiple database connected ?